# Purpose of expanding then shrinking in SHA-1

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, sha-1

What is the purpose of expanding then shrinking in SHA-1? Does it serves any security purposes?

Answer (score 12):

*Expanding then shrinking* in SHA-1 refers to the process, performed for each round (each 512-bit block of padded message), of

- message expansion from 512 bits to 2560 bits;
- keeping only 160 bits of state for the next round.

The later directly follows from the construction of SHA-1 as a [Merkle-Damgård](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#The_Merkle.E2.80.93Damg.C3.A5rd_construction) hash of 160 bit. The former occurs because SHA-1's [compression function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function) is built from a block cipher using the [Davies-Meyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Davies.E2.80.93Meyer) construction, that is with the message entering the block cipher's (512-bit) key input; and, as most block ciphers do, the particular block cipher used in SHA-1 uses a [key schedule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_schedule), expanding the key to 80 subkeys (each 32-bit), one per round.

The expanding in SHA-1 is thus the key schedule of its block cipher, and is there to make SHA-1's internal block cipher secure, making SHA-1's compression function collision-resistant, making SHA-1 collision-resistant.

As an illustration that the key schedule/expansion plays a security role, the short-lived SHA (now known by the retronym SHA-0) differs from SHA-1 by a weaker key schedule (with one less word rotation), and is more badly broken than SHA-1 is (in particular, by  Yusuke Naito, Yu Sasaki, Takeshi Shimoyama, Jun Yajima, Noboru Kunihiro, Kazuo Ohta: [*Improved Collision Search for SHA-0*](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11935230_2), in proceedings of ASIACRYPT 2006).